# Displaying transparent background in conversion from PNG to JPEG for jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, jspdf

I am using `jsPDF` to convert images within `canvas` to `toDataURL()`. Specifically I am dealing with `PNG`'s that once converted to `JPEG` and saved to a `PDF` file using the `jsPDF` plugin.  I recieve a black background.  I know this has to do with the `PNG` being able to  handle transparent backgrounds and `JPEG` unable to register that.  I know there are work arounds by creating some sort of background to replace the black background already inserted within that newly created `JPEG` but I am not sure how I can accomplish this?

Suggestions, thoughts?

Heres what I am doing:

```
       $(".email_button").click(function(){
            // LOOP THROUGH EACH CANVAS SECTION AND STORE THE DATA INTO PDF FORM USING JSPDF CONVERT 
            var canvas = $(".ifp_container_printing_15 canvas").get();
            var imgData = canvas[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            console.log(imgData);
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 60,50);           
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var canvas = $(".ifp_container_printing_15 canvas").get(0);
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```